# When you remove a vote, that vote doesn't go back into your vote pool

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, vote-count

A few minutes ago I had the message

> 5 votes remaining today

I voted on 4 more posts.  The last one I decided retract my vote, then decided I was correct and re-posted the same vote.

After recasting that 4th vote, I received the message that I was out of votes, i.e.:

*Start with 5 Votes*

1 - Vote on Q1
2 - Vote on Q2
3 - Vote on Q3
4 - Vote on Q4
- Remove vote on Q4
5 - Vote on Q4 a second time

**This indicates to me that when you remove a vote, that vote doesn't go back into your vote pool**

Can anyone else reproduce this?  Is it intentional behavior?

**Update:**

Possibly related.  I received the `Vox Populi` badge today for hitting the 40 vote cap, but my [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) indicates I only cast 39 votes today.

**Update II:**

I now have another vote to use somehow.  Was there a recalc or internal procedure that had to run or did an admin do something manually because I posted this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you were awarded the badge, you did have 40 votes on active posts.  Then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808689/errors-when-including-own-class-that-has-no-syntax-errors) was deleted, freeing up a vote spot during the time you posted here and your edits.

I'm at a loss on how to explain the messages you received, though.  You did cast a few votes very quickly near the vote limit, but I can't repro, even in unit tests.

Let us know if you experience this again.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.  I was more concerned that removed votes were not added back into the pool but it sounds like that is not the case.